# Por que somem os dados da form ao puxar CEP?

Tags: jquery, html5, angularjs

Fiz uma tela de edição de dados, e o problema que está ocorrendo é que quando coloco o cep os dados do endereço aparecem, mas os dados, já preenchidos somem!
Alguém pode me ajudar?

HTML:

```
<form name="formPerfilStartup">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <p id="cep">CEP</p>
            <input class="campoCep" type="text" name="cep" ng-model="perfilNovaStartup.cep">
            <p id="cidade">Cidade</p>
            <input class="campoCidade" type="text" name="localidade" ng-model="perfilNovaStartup.localidade">
            <p id="estado">Estado</p>
            <input class="selectEstado" type="text" name="uf" id="" ng-model="perfilNovaStartup.uf">
            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <p id="startup">Nome Startup</p>
                    <input class="startup" type="text" name="nomeStartup" ng-model="perfilNovaStartup.nomeStartup">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 ">
                    <p id="descricao">Descriçãp (resumo)</p>
                    <textarea name="resumo" cols="49" rows="5" ng-model="perfilNovaStartup.resumo" 
                    placeholder="Sou engenheiro elétrico a 10 anos...">

                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

JS que traz os dados do cep e os demais dados:

```
app.controller("editarPerfilStartupCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

$scope.idusuario = localStorage.getItem("startwe_idusuario");
$scope.usuario = localStorage.getItem("startwe_usuario");
$scope.idstartup = $routeParams.idstartup;
console.log(`id usuario ${$scope.idusuario}, usuario ${$scope.usuario}, id startup ${$scope.idstartup}`)

if(location.hostname == 'localhost'){
    var urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:8888/sistemas/Webapps/Projetos/startWe/api/registerStartup.php';
    var urlOptionPrefix = 'http://localhost:8888/sistemas/Webapps/Projetos/startWe/api/registerStartup.php?option=';
} else {
    var urlPrefix = '';
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.campoCep').focusout(function(){
        var valorCep = $('.campoCep').val();
        $http.get('http://viacep.com.br/ws/'+valorCep+'/json/').then(function(response){
            if(response.data.erro == true){
                $scope.erro = 'CEP inexistente! Tente novamente.';
            }
            $scope.perfilNovaStartup = response.data;
        })
    })

});

var pegarStartup = function(){
    var option = 'pegar startup';
    var idstartup = $scope.idstartup;
    $http.get(urlOptionPrefix + option + '&idstartup=' + idstartup).then(function(response){
        //console.log(response.data)
        $scope.perfilNovaStartup = response.data;
    })

}
pegarStartup();

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, você atualiza todo o conteúdo do model "perfilNovaStartup" quando você executa a função "pegarStartup" ou quando você pesquisa o CEP. Por isso é que quando você pesquisa o CEP você apaga o nome e o resumo.

Para evitar este problema, ao pesquisar o CEP, você deveria alterar apenas os campos do model referente ao CEP. Como eu não tenho o retorno da pesquisa, eu imagino que a alteração depois de retornar o CEP seja assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.campoCep').focusout(function(){
        var valorCep = $('.campoCep').val();
        $http.get('http://viacep.com.br/ws/'+valorCep+'/json/').then(function(response){
            if(response.data.erro == true){
                $scope.erro = 'CEP inexistente! Tente novamente.';
            }
   $scope.perfilNovaStartup.cep = response.data.cep;
   $scope.perfilNovaStartup.localidade = response.data.localidade;
   $scope.perfilNovaStartup.uf = response.data.uf;
        })
    })

});
```

Comment: Valeu, vou testar